# How to Display laravel session cart values in Vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on a Shopping cart in laravel and vue js, The cart works fine in laravel foreach loop as i know the method to extract the values from session in laravel format but my problem is that i want to display the session('cart') now using v-for. I know there is some problem in my understanding of the response coming from controller but i can't handle it in vue js.

My Controller from where i am sending the session('cart')

```
public function fetchCart(){
        $cart = session('cart');
        return $cart;
        

    }
```

My blade file code on which i am trying to display it

```
<script>
 var vcart = new Vue({
        el:'#cart',
        data:{
            cart:{},
            result:[],
            total:0,
        },
        methods:{

  displaycart:function(){
        axios.get('/fetch/cart').then((res)=>{

            this.cart = res.data;
            console.log(this.cart);

           



            
            
        })
    }
    
    },
},
    mounted(){
        
        this.displaycart();
    }
</script>
```

The response which i have logged in console

```
{__ob__: Observer}
1: Object
  on expanding   
         id: 1
         image: "https://www.techpowerup.com/img/ataZdYFc0NyRhMuU.jpg"
         name: "GPU"
         price: 23999
         quantity: 1
2: Object
 same as above
5: Object
```

Error I get in console

Property or method "row" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: Is `/fetch/cart` defined in api.php or web.php?

Comment: it is web.php route to my controller code to get session('cart')

Comment: You defined cart as object, but result is an array.

Comment: I have also tried it as an array

Comment: can you provide the part you use v-for ?

Comment: this is my v-for part
 <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(row,key,index) in cart" :key="row.id">
                      <td>@{{ row.name }}</td>
                  </tr>
                       


              </tbody>

It isn't displaying anything
I am getting response but can't figure out how to access data to display

Comment: it's because your iteration. Iterate like this : `v-for="(row,index)" in cart`

Comment: Still not working it is giving error now "Property or method "row" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"
and
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: did you also change cart to array?

Comment: yes i tried it like this but not working
tried like : 
 public function fetchCart(){
        
        
            $cart = array(session('cart'));
        return session('cart');
        

    }

Comment: no I mean in your vue's data. cart is defined as object not array

Comment: yes i have defined as array 
and another point is that the data that i am receiving from fetch method isnt being assigned to cart:[]